# How to get an Image position on the scene? (Java)

Tags: java, image, draw, scene

I have some Image variable seems like that:  `Image fe9 = new Image("/kepek/fekete_korong.png");`

and I drawed to the scene like that:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas( 900, 700 ); // 900,700 the scene high and width
    root.getChildren().add( canvas );

    startKirajzol( canvas );

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

  public void startKirajzol( Canvas canvas ){

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.drawImage( fe9 , 850, 650 );
}
```

How can I get the `fe9` variable postion on the scene? (so the 850 and 650)

I liked to use for example:

```
if( fe9.getIdontHowNowThePositionX == 850 ){
System.out.println("Hurre!")
}
```

Comment: Easiest would be to save them as variables...

Comment: I like to write a mill board game, and I will move this image, and the easiest way for me If I always can get the position if I like but yes it is a good idea, thanks! :)